# C - Get the number of digits in a double

Tags: c, string, double

This question has been asked but I can't find a satisfying answer.

I need to get the number of digits in a double without knowing what it is, and zeroes can be anywhere.

For example, if it is 12.00032110, I need to get the number 11 (with the dot and counting the zero at the end)

I try converting them to strings to get their length, but for that I need to get know their length beforehand because I need to specify a precision. if I go with "%.5f" then all of them will have 5 digits after the dot, and therefore I can't get their original length. If I go with "%f" all the longer ones are truncated, and I cannot get their original lengths.

What is the solution to this? I have been searching for an answer the whole day, without success.

Comment: The number of digits cannot be determined *that* easily. Your example number cannot even be expressed exactly in a double, and is approximated with `12.000321100000000740237737773`. Please re-think your question.

Comment: `12` is the same as `12.0000000000000` so, what is the point of getting the number of digits? Please clarify what you are trying to get to and what you are planing on doing with the number of digits

Comment: You can't take the length with the last 0 included.Why? Because in C there is no difference between `double a = 2.32813;` and `double a = 2.32813000;` - they are represented the same.
The only way you could do that is to read the number in an array of chars and parse every char from array and increment a counter only if there is something on that array position. At last you have the counter which would be the length of the number.

Comment: Converting floating point values into strings can be inherently inaccurate, see http://floating-point-gui.de.

Comment: You need to begin by defining what you mean by the length. Every double can be converted exactly to a decimal string, but that string may have hundreds of significant digits. The exact decimal fraction representation of the double closest to 12.0003211 is 12.00032110000000074023773777298629283905029296875. One of the answers suggests counting the number of significant digits in the shortest decimal fraction that, if parsed as a double, would yield the input. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to find the shortest string that will yield your number when converted to a decimal floating-point number. The function below does this (provided you supply a sufficiently long char buffer) by repeatedly writing and scanning with increasing precision:

```
char *strfloat(char buf[], int n, double d)
{
    int p;

    for (p = 0; p < 20; p++) {
        double x;

        if (snprintf(buf, n, "%.*g", p, d) >= n) break;;
        sscanf(buf, "%lf", &x);
        if (x == d) break;
    }

    return buf;
}
```

Your length is the `strlen` of the string held by the buffer. You'll never get a fractional number with trailing zeros, though.